# c# asp.net core register nested generic class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class GenericList<T> : IRequest<Attempt<IQueryable<T>>>
{
}

public class GenericListHandler<T> : IRequestHandler<GenericList<T>, Attempt<IQueryable<T>>> where T: class
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _databaseContext;
    public GenericListHandler(DatabaseContext databaseContext) => _databaseContext = databaseContext;

    public async Task<Attempt<IQueryable<T>>> Handle(GenericList<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        Attempt<IQueryable<T>>.Succeed(_databaseContext.Set<T>());
}
```

And I would like to register that in my **Startup** class.
I tried doing this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(GenericListHandler<>), typeof(GenericListHandler<>));
```

But it doesn't resolve. I believe because it needs to resolve to `IRequestHandler<GenericList<T>, Attempt<IQueryable<T>>>`, so I tried to do this:

```
services.AddTransient(serviceType: typeof(IRequestHandler<GenericList<>, Attempt<IQueryable<>>>),typeof(GenericListHandler<>));
```

But it doesn't like it. I get this error:

> Unexpected use of an unbound generic name

I have also tried:

```
services.AddTransient(serviceType: typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),typeof(GenericListHandler<>));
```

and while this does compile, it doesn't fine the correct handler.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What are you injecting this object into?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you should specify some types for the generics, they are dependencies too and must be resolved too

Comment: so specifying that `T` is a `class` is not enough?

Comment: I have another geneic class that does this: `where T : TClass<TKey>` is that what you mean?

Comment: `Autofac` allows registering [open generics](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components). You can combine with [scanning feature](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#specifying-services).

Comment: im not using autofac; im using .net core :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (albeit not a very elegant one).
Apprently, you can't register nested generics:

[Cannot register nested generic interface in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786924/cannot-register-nested-generic-interface-in-net-core)

so instead I had to do this:

```
private static void AddGenericList(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Attribute>, Attempt<IQueryable<Attribute>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Attribute>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Brand>, Attempt<IQueryable<Brand>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Brand>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Category>, Attempt<IQueryable<Category>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Category>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Conversion>, Attempt<IQueryable<Conversion>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Conversion>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Criterion>, Attempt<IQueryable<Criterion>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Criterion>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Exclusion>, Attempt<IQueryable<Exclusion>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Exclusion>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Feed>, Attempt<IQueryable<Feed>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Feed>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<FieldMap>, Attempt<IQueryable<FieldMap>>>,
            GenericListHandler<FieldMap>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Field>, Attempt<IQueryable<Field>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Field>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Filter>, Attempt<IQueryable<Filter>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Filter>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Floor>, Attempt<IQueryable<Floor>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Floor>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Formula>, Attempt<IQueryable<Formula>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Formula>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Plan>, Attempt<IQueryable<Plan>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Plan>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Rule>, Attempt<IQueryable<Rule>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Rule>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Theatre>, Attempt<IQueryable<Theatre>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Theatre>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Transformation>, Attempt<IQueryable<Transformation>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Transformation>>();
    services
        .AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GenericList<Venue>, Attempt<IQueryable<Venue>>>,
            GenericListHandler<Venue>>();
}
```

Which isn't the most ideal solution, but it does work.

Comment: The above can be be refactored to use reflection as well. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Could you provide an example? :D